Visual Studio 2022 with SonarQube for VS not showing warnings/messages in Error List
One of my colleague's VS 2022 is not showing Sonar's warnings & messages in the Error List.  We have compared all the settings we know of, but their system is behaving differently.  Any suggestions on what to check would be greatly appreciated.
There is an .editorconfig with the solution.  We have compared the VS settings/options.  He has uninstalled and reinstalled the extension.
